# Python dictionary.values() to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a dict using python 3:

```
d = {'w1': np.array([12,11,23]), 'w2':np.array([1,2,3])}
```

and some variable with an integer say

```
a=12
```

How do I turn the dict values and integer into one numpy array so that it looks like this?

```
array([12, array([12, 11, 23]), array([1, 2, 3])])
```

I've tried:

```
np.array([a,(list(d.values()))],dtype=object)
```

and I get:

```
array([12, list([array([12, 11, 23]), array([1, 2, 3])])], dtype=object)
```

but I don't want the list in the second index, I want it to be "unpacked".

Comment: Are you sure you need a `np.array` of objects? Why not just work with a `list` e.g. `[12] + list(d.values())`

Comment: Yeah, you don't really get much benefit out of an array of objects, especially a small one. You can't vectorize any operations for performance, or even get much convenience benefit out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to put the arrays in an inner list, just don't put them in a list:

```
>>> np.array([a, *d.values()], dtype=object)
array([12, array([12, 11, 23]), array([1, 2, 3])], dtype=object)
```

Or, if you're on an older Python and can't unpack into a list display, create the list, but add it to another one to get the same flat list:

```
>>> np.array([a] + list(d.values()), dtype=object)
array([12, array([12, 11, 23]), array([1, 2, 3])], dtype=object)
```